# Syntax information for pure functions

Tags: function-construction, syntax, syntax-highlighting

Mathematica's help on [SyntaxInformation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) does not rule out syntax information for pure functions.

> SyntaxInformation[f] gives information used to generate syntax coloring and other advisories when f[…] is entered as input.

The naive code

```
f = # &;
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}}
```

fails with a message about the first argument. Using the string instead of the symbol

```
SyntaxInformation["f"] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}}
```

does not throw a message but it does not produce the expected red parameters in `f[a,b]`.

Is there any way to specify syntax information on pure functions?

Comment: `SyntaxInformation` works at the `Symbol` level. Call it before assigning to `f`.

Comment: Although the solution is quite simple, it is far from trivial. Write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SyntaxInformation` does not hold its arguments so you can hold it:

```
f // ClearAll
f = # &;
f // Unevaluated // SyntaxInformation = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};
```

as an alternative to altering the order:

```
f // ClearAll
f // SyntaxInformation = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};
f = # &;
```